# Wwise Resonance Audio Room behaving strangely in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, resonance-audio

I am trying to implement Resonance Audio via Wwise for a game in Unity, but I have a problem I can not solve for the life of me.

The problem is that the zones where I can hear the room reverb doesn't correspond to the set room boundaries. I've uploaded a video to illustrate the problem. Each room in the game has a WwiseResonanceAudioRoom component attached to it, with no change in scale, that fits the room. But for each of the three rooms, I can only hear the room reverb in some specific part of the room. Some reverb for objects on a longer distance can be heard from parts of the room where the others can't be heard. I've added a debugging box to the game view which outputs the exact data that the ResonanceAudio.cs script is sending to Wwise. In Wwise, all of the reverbed sounds are sent to a "RoomEffectsMasterBus" with the Resonance Audio mixer plugin on it, as well as an ambisonic aux bus (which I turned the volume down on for the video). The regular sound works well, and I'm using Wwise Rooms to separate the room sounds.

How the hell do I make Resonance Audio output room reverbs in the entire room? I haven't touched the Resonance Audio scripts (other than now adding the debug text output). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using
 
- Wwise 2019.2.0.7216
- Resonance Audio SDK 2019.2.1.91 from Wwise Launcher
- Unity 2019.2.17f1
- The ResonanceAudioForWWise 1.2.1 Unity-Wwise implementation wrapper scripts for Unity

Here's the video showing the issue:
https://youtu.be/0Y7GXG69IZ0

Room 2 boundaries [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatEy.png)
Room 1 boundaries [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XtZm.png)

Comment: Did you try to remove (not disable) all other audio listeners?  aka from https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-resonance-audio-room-not-working-correctly-after-importing-project.698378/#post-4671713

Comment: Yes, I only have one copy each of AudioListener, AkAudioListener and AkSpatialAudioListener, all on the main camera.